# Работа с элементами списка

Tags: python, функции, списки

Что надо изменить, чтобы при выводе имени, писалась дополнительная информация о нем?

```
import random 
import random 

child = ['natasha','Serega','Youri','Potap','Prohor']
print(random.choice(child))
for child in child:
if child == 'natasha':
    print('natasha' + 'bad people')
if child == 'Serega':
    print('Serega' +'good people')
if child == 'Youri':
    print('Youri' + 'very good people')
if child == 'Potap':
    print('Potap' + 'little children')
if child == 'Alina':
    print('Prohor' + 'first grade student')
```

Comment: Переменная цикла Child перекрыла список с таким же именем, поэтому: for ch in child или переименуйте список в children

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю изменить модель немного и воспользоваться словарём:

```
import random

children= {'natasha':'bad people',
           'Serega':'good people',
           'Youri':'very good people',
           'Potap':'little children',
           'Prohor':'first grade student'}

child = random.choice(list(children.keys()))
print("{} {}".format(child, children[child]))
```

Comment: мне на питоне надо

Comment: прощу прощения,спасибо за помощь

Comment: @python'ист, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)